# Postfix body_checks regexp expression does not work?

Tags: postfix, regex, spam-filter

I have a a reject rule inside body_checks parameter written like this:

```
/(\d{3,4},\d{2} EUR)/ REJECT Body Spam Rule 934
```

This regexp paramater should be ok, at least according to some testing pages where you can test regexp, for example on [this](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex) page. So, I test it against this sentence

```
Sie haben eine Zahlung über 156,36 EUR
```

But when I test with real e-mail containing above sentences, the email is not rejected.

Postfix has enabled header and body checks. Other non regexp rules works fine. I have also reloaded postfix service after adding filter to body_checks. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post applicable postfix configuration files?

Comment: Any idea how to copy the whole content of .cf file threw ssh? :P

Comment: You need post all lines in your body_checks file. Maybe some regexp rules overriding this regexp. Try to place the regexp above the others.

Comment: All lines are inside body_checks file. main.cf references to body checks files threw header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks. I also moved rule above all rules, but the problem remains.

Comment: Is this a test email you created or a real spam email from a spammer?  If it's a spammer email, it could easily contain different characters such as a tab instead of a space or a non-printable character or alternate unicode characters such as the fullwidth digits (U+FF1x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like postfix doesn't support`\d` in regex. Replace it with `[0-9]` to make it work.

```
/([0-9]{3,4},[0-9]{2} EUR)/ REJECT Body Spam Rule 934
```

Postmap result

```
~$ postmap -bmq - regexp:/etc/postfix/myregex  < sample-body
Sie haben eine Zahlung über 156,36 EUR  REJECT Body Spam Rule 93156,36 EUR
```

Comment: thank you, thank you 100 times :). You made my day. It works now!!!